# how to combine multiple lines into single line in unix?

Tags: unix

### My text file is like this:-

> <first_load_time>29-09-2020</first_load_time>
> <sql_id>qqkbwi76786</sql_id>

> <first_load_time>01-01-2020</first_load_time>
> <sql_id>abcdef12345</sql_id>

### Desired output:-

a text file in below format

> <first_load_time>29-09-2020</first_load_time><sql_id>qqkbwi76786</sql_id
> <first_load_time>01-01-2020</first_load_time><sql_id>abcdef12345</sql_id>

Note:-

1. There is a empty line between first two blocks in input text file. The empty line separates blocks of text in the text file, In output file i need each block of text in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input in some file, say input.txt, you can find any blank lines (in regex `^$` meaning start followed immediately by end of line) in sed and delete them (with  `d`), and send to an output file say putput.txt:

```
sed '/^$/ d' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below awk command :

```
awk '$1 ~ "<first" {a=$0;next;} $1 ~ "<sql"  {print a $0}' file.txt
```

This command will check for the pattern "<first" in the input line. If the pattern matches, then it will store the line in a variable and move on to next line. If the next line has pattern "<sql", then it will print the line stored in variable a and current line starting with <sql.

Since this command is matching pattern, it will automatically ignore blank lines.